Does yarn berry supports execution of uninstall script when removing module
I am facing issue with yarn 3 which was working fine with yarn 1.x.
when using yarn 3 , i am adding a local module using yarn add which has some hooks defined in its package.json like as below
"scripts": {
    "install": "node ./scripts/install.js",
    "postinstall":"node ./scripts/post_install.js",
    "uninstall": "node ./scripts/cleanup.js"
  },

when i remove the module using yarn remove Module_name then cleanup.js is not getting executed and neither i get any error.
Note:

install and post install are working fine on yarn 3 . only issue
with yarn3

since using --verbose gives error on yarn3 , is it possible some way to trouble shoot and see error logs if any.


Please help
Env: Mac OS, NodeJs: 18.x
